# Turn number inside a list to number outside a list; a string

Tags: python, string, list

I extracted just a number from a string with:

`weight = [int(s) for s in fish.split() if s.isdigit()]` , the result is a `list`: `[7088]`

I try to turn that list into a string by doing:

`weight = str(weight)
print("weight:", weight)` but the printout remains:

`weight: [7088]`

So I tried returning just an integer with:

`weight = int(weight)` but got:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[7088]'`

So instead I tried converting the initial list number to a float with:

`weight = float(weight)` but got:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[7088]'`

Ultimately this causes my code to fail because my RegEx doesn't recognize that as a number. (RegEx: `regnumber = re.compile(r"(\d),(\d) | (\d)")`)

Is there a simple way to turn the initial returned number inside of a list into a number/string/integer than my RegEx can actually recognize?

Comment: pretty sure you overthought the problem. Consider taking a break :D

Comment: don't turn it into an `int` to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just one number in the list always, you can do:

```
weight = str(weight[0])
```

or use float(), int(), etc, based on your requirement

Comment: or int(weight[0])

Comment: Thanks. Idk if I was overthinking it per say but I was definitely being dumb about it. Thanks for helping me out though

Answer (score 1):

Obvious is not to turn it into an int to begin with:

```
weight = [s for s in fish.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

but if you must:

```
weight = map(str, weight)
```